How to Ensure Custom Script Runs After swift-openapi-generator in Xcode Build Process?
I'm currently developing an iOS project using Swift and Xcode, and I use swift-openapi-generator to generate Swift code from an openapi.json file.
To manage dependencies, I use Swift Package Manager (SPM). Here is how my Package.swift looks:
// swift-tools-version:5.8

import Foundation
import PackageDescription

let openAPIRuntime = Target.Dependency.product(name: "OpenAPIRuntime", package: "swift-openapi-runtime")
let openAPIURLSession = Target.Dependency.product(name: "OpenAPIURLSession", package: "swift-openapi-urlsession")
let openAPIGenerator = Target.PluginUsage.plugin(name: "OpenAPIGenerator", package: "swift-openapi-generator")

let targets: [Target] = [
    .target(
        name: "OpenAPIClient",
        dependencies: [openAPIRuntime, openAPIURLSession],
        plugins: [openAPIGenerator]
    ),
    //...
]

let package = Package(
    name: "Modules",
    platforms: [.iOS("16.0"), .macOS(.v11)],
    products: targets.filter { !$0.isTest }.map { .library(name: $0.name, targets: [$0.name]) },
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-generator", from: "0.1.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-runtime", from: "1.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/apple/swift-openapi-urlsession", from: "1.0.0"),
        //...
    ],
    targets: targets
)

The openapi.json file employs snake_case rather than camelCase. I’d like to follow the Swift naming guide and use camelCase instead. Unfortunately, there’s no direct way to generate the Swift code with camelCase if openapi.json uses snake_case.
So, I wrote a custom script that iterates over the generated code and replaces snake_case with camelCase.
The problem I’m facing is that my script runs before the generator plugin. I’ve tried to place my script in build-pre-actions and build-phases, but none of the above worked.
How can I ensure that my custom script runs after the generator plugin during the build process?
